# Adblock plus Chrome extension uses requireJS, but library not found on extension folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I am trying to analyze the codes of adblock plus and realized that it uses requireJS library to include files. But I can't find requireJS library to be able to use it in the extension.Why its not found in the extension folder? I'm stuck with no satisfactory explanation.am I missing something or doing wrong ?

Comment: @ArnoChauveau there should be mainConfigFile anyway right ?I cant find a single link that connects the requireJS library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the `compat.js` file. You will see that `require(module)` is just a function. Also, read the `background.js` file for how `with` keyword is used. More info about `with` keyword [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

All the html files already have this file loaded in the scripts tag, hence this can be used everywhere.

So this is not the `requireJS` library's `require` that you are searching for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: lolz.. I cant believe I diverted all the way from normal analysis because of a particular keyword.thanks

Answer (score -1):

If there is no local library in the extension folder, it's possible they are using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), such as [this one](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/require.js/), to include what they need in their project

Comment: Any way there should be a link to CDN right ? but i dont think its there in the extension.completely null.

Comment: I searched the entire chrome extension files for **require** but there is nothing that defines require.its directly used as require to import files.